# Java: How to get the complete path with a directoryChooser?

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I'm using a `directoryChooser` to choose the path for saving files.

If I run the code, the `directoryChooser` opens and I go to the path 
"D:/Projects/TestFiles/Income".

I use the method `directoryChooser.getCurrentDirectory()` and set a label with `setText()` (displayed in the `JFrame`) to this path.
The label is not displaying the complete Path, just "D:/Projects/TestFiles" is showing. The last folder (step of the path) is missing...

```
DirectoryChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
```

is used for filtering.

How can I get the complete path?

Comment: Is the directorychooser a JFileChooser?

Answer (score 1):

getCurrentDirectory() will give the path to the current folder being browsed.

Try using JFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() to get the path to the selected file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile--

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`setText(JFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the Present Working Directory using `File` object first and then set the current directory of FileChooser using `setCurrentDirectory()`. Like this:

```
File workingDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
DirectoryChooser.setCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);
```

then you can set the text of your jLabel:

```
jLabel1.setText(DirectoryChooser.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
```